# Seperation of variables differnetial equation $t^2 \frac{dy}{dt} - t = 1 + y + ty$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$t^2 \frac{dy}{dt} - t = 1 + y + ty$$

Obviously this problem is meant to trick you, I am sure there is some simple solution but after 20 minutes I don't know.

How do you approach something like this>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: We start with $$t^{2}\frac{dy}{dt} - t = 1 + y + ty$$

Move $t$ over to the right side and factor:

$$t^{2}\frac{dy}{dt} = (y+1)(t+1)$$

Now separate to obtain:

$$\frac{dy}{y+1} = \frac{t+1}{t^{2}}dt$$

Can you solve from here?

Comment: How could you possibly know to do that? I would have spent hours on this on a test.

Comment: @PaulthePirate practice, practice, practice. Then practice some more. The more problems you do, the more problems you will become familiar with and learn how to solve, the more tricks you will learn, and the more your understanding will expand. I'm not any smarter than you, I've just done this before - so keep at it!! :)

Comment: No more practice time :(